# React Native Exception thrown while executing UI block

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Whenever I run a react native app on IOS i get the following error , I am not able to figure it out what's actually causing it.

[image: Screenshot of the error is attached]

```
Error: Exception thrown while executing UI block:
***[__NSArrayMsetObject:atIndexedSubscript:]:object cannot be nil
```

Comment: Please add some code so that we can understand question better!.
as there can be many reasons why this must be happening, maybe you are passing null somewhere in a native module or passing a wrong data type, there can be many reason, to understand better add your screen files. although it can be because of some native libraries.

Comment: I have solved a simillar problem here for Victory Native: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73302893/614065