# Exception thrown while executing UI block: 'parentNode' is a required a required parameter

Tags: react-native

Exception thrown while executing UI block: 'parentNode' is a required parameterException thrown while executing UI block: 'parentNode' is a required parameter

im getting this error when trying to render a list in react native.
what can i do about it
?

Comment: Can you post the code of the component you are trying to render?

Comment: Without your code sample, we won't be able to give accurate input.

Answer (score 4):

the reason for this error is are you using parameter name same as an already declared variable in that component, like below

```
let a;
this.props.navigation.navigate(screen,{a:1})
```

you can fix the error by using a new parameter name like

```
let a;
this.props.navigation.navigate(screen,{b:1})
```

Answer (score 4):

Had the same problem, coming from react-native Animated

What worked for me :

```
Disable useNativeDriver :

/* Error */
Animated.timing(fade, {
  toValue: 20,
  duration: 800,
  useNativeDriver: true <--- change to false
}).start();
```

Answer (score 1):

This error happened to me when trying to dispatch an Animated timing event and instead of accessing an animated value within an Animated.View component I was using a regular rn View.

Comment: I was getting the same error. Resolved it by removing the borderColor, borderRadius & borderWidth from Text styles.

Comment: I had `useMemo` elements inside the animated component and what is worse influenced on other app's parts (the animation worked well...). Removed `useMemo` from memorized component's parts and everything started working.

Answer (score 1):

I have received this error for my `Victory Native` bar chart. There was problems with bar clicks on `Android` and I have solved it by providing a `Svg` container component:

```js
<VictoryChart containerComponent={isAndroid ? <Svg /> : undefined}>
```

You also need to wrap the chart with a  container to bar clicks work on iOS but don't use `containerComponent` instead wrap it with an outside container:

```js
interface Props {
  children: React.ReactNode;
  width?: number;
  height?: number;
}

const ChartWrapper = (props: Props) => {
  const {children, height, width} = props;
  return isAndroid ?
    <View style={{width, height}}>{children}</View> :
    <Pressable style={{height, width}}>{children}</Pressable>;
};
```

in chart screen:

```js
<ChartWrapper width={windowWidth}>
  <VictoryChart containerComponent={isAndroid ? <Svg /> : undefined}>
    <VictoryBar />
  </VictoryChart>
</ChartWrapper>
```

Answer (score 0):

We had  'react-native-fast-image' version  "8.6.3" in our code base

Before: The tintColor was passed as a prop directly to the FastImage component. This is being removed from the props and being applied directly in the style.

```
 <FastImage
      tintColor={'red'}//remove this line
      resizeMode={FastImage.resizeMode.contain}
      source={require('images/home.png')}
      style={{
        priority: FastImage.priority.normal,
        width: iconSize,
        height: iconSize,
      }}
    />
```

After: The tintColor is now directly included in the style object of the FastImage component.

```
<FastImage
      resizeMode={FastImage.resizeMode.contain}
      source={require('images/home.png')}
      style={{
        priority: FastImage.priority.normal,
        width: iconSize,
        height: iconSize,
        tintColor:'red'//add here
      }}
    />
```